# react-helmet throws "Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using react-helmet in my projects throws:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I know it's using React 15 and thus the error. But is there an alternative library that is not using React 15 methods and works the same?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you can do about this since the `react-helmet` library is using `componentWillMount` internally. You can find an issue on their repo [here](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/465).

A possible solution is to use `react-helmet-async` instead, but I recommend you read on what's different before changing one for the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude :)